# Cannot access apache2 serve

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, apache-http-server

I have machine 1 running Fedora 20 64 KDE running apache2 and openssh server having IP 192.168.0.10 connected via crossover cable (cat 5e) to my machine 2 running Fedora 20 64 cinnamon IP 192.168.0.1 I can access machine 1 from machine 2 using ssh and can also ping it but when I type the IP of machine 1 in machine 2's web browser I cant get to that apache server. But from machine 1 I can access apache2 by typing localhost or the IP 192.168.0.10

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any firewall rule trying to reject the apache connection attempt from the outside world in Machine 2. Give `allow from all` in apache configuration file. This will solve the problem.